# In Pycharm problem with pd.read_table(url)

Tags: python, pandas

Can't open an URL with this simple command => pd.read_table(url)

---

import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/chipotle.tsv"

array = pd.read_table(url)

### print(array)

The end of the message error is:
"urllib.error.URLError: "

Comment: works for me. what packages/versions do you have installed? probably an env issue

Comment: would be helpful to post exact traceback

Comment: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)>

Comment: what do you mean by venv issue? Thanks you

Comment: What is your python version? 3.6? If so, try running /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command